# Redirecting to another page along with url parameters does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

So in one page, I have a button that when is clicked

```
<button ng-click="try()">try</button>
```

has to take you to the home page and greet you

```
//inside one page controller

 $scope.try = function() {
     //they are dynamic, so they change. 
     var name= localstorage.get("name");
     var pre = localstorage.get("pre");
     var msg = true;
    $location.path("/"+msg+"/"+pre+"/"+name);
  };
```

So take those vars (msg, name and pre) and pass the to the home page.

Home page is defined like so

```
            .when('/' || '/:msg/:pre/:name', {                      
               templateUrl: 'home.html',                         
               controller: 'homeController'
           })
```

and home page controller is

```
    app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {            
            var param1 = $routeParams.msg;
            var param2 = $routeParams.pre;
            var param3 = $routeParams.name;
            alert("param1  >  "+ param1);
            alert("param2  >  "+ param2);
            alert("param3  >  "+ param3);
    });
```

I always get `undifined`.

How do I set the vars in the parameters, so this will work? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: here you have only params in url how it will redirect you atleast have some text before that which is fixed like a/msg/pre/name , a/msg1/pre1/name1 then it will work.

Comment: @Amit This is the home page, so it has no text, its `/` not like `/whatever`. And it does redirect me.

Comment: can you make a plunker?